# Конфликт jQuery в ModX

Tags: modx, jquery, javascript

Привет всем посетителям этого сайта.

Хотел бы спросить, у вас такую штуку о ModX'e.
Есть у него такой замечательный "барчик", который выводится на страницу самого сайта если авторизоваться в ЦМСке под admin'ом. Такая синенькая полосочка.

Добавляясь к основному содержимому, она добавляет в head свои необходимые скрипты, которые в моем случае вызывают конфликт с одной из каруселей.

Не хотелось бы чтобы этот конфликт был виден, для этого хочу поправить хеад который он вставляет.

Может кто-нибудь знает где он в модыксе хранится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Попробуйте в плагине Quick Manager+ в
> конфигурации плагина параметр «Load
> jQuery in front-end» поставить false.

А пробовали использовать метод .[noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)?

Comment: Спасибо большое, иногда не хватает что бы кто-то просто назвал все своими именами.

Дело оказалось параметрах Quick Manager+ но с праметром "jQuery noConflict mode in front-end" после его выключения все заработало, я так понял что он просто выключает все стальные jquery, или библотеки.